# GKE cluster nodes not uncordoned after upgrade

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a zonal GKE cluster with 1 node with settings:

```
Size: 1
Auto-scaling: Off
Auto-upgrade: Enabled
Auto-repair: Enabled
Surge upgrade: Disabled
```

Every now and then, the Node Pool gets upgraded to the current master. The single node is Cordoned, Deleted, Created and... never gets Uncordoned - so the effect is that the previously running deployments get stuck in "waiting state".

What am I missing? why is the node never un-cordoned? shouldn't that be part of the upgrade process?

Cluster details (from describe)

```
addonsConfig:
  cloudRunConfig:
    disabled: true
    loadBalancerType: LOAD_BALANCER_TYPE_EXTERNAL
  configConnectorConfig: {}
  dnsCacheConfig: {}
  gcePersistentDiskCsiDriverConfig: {}
  horizontalPodAutoscaling: {}
  httpLoadBalancing:
    disabled: true
  istioConfig:
    disabled: true
  kalmConfig: {}
  kubernetesDashboard:
    disabled: true
  networkPolicyConfig:
    disabled: true
authenticatorGroupsConfig: {}
clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.48.0.0/14
clusterTelemetry:
  type: ENABLED
createTime: '2020-06-20T16:13:18+00:00'
currentMasterVersion: 1.18.10-gke.2101
currentNodeCount: 1
currentNodeVersion: 1.18.10-gke.2101
databaseEncryption:
  state: DECRYPTED
defaultMaxPodsConstraint:
  maxPodsPerNode: '110'
endpoint: ...
initialClusterVersion: 1.16.8-gke.15
instanceGroupUrls:
- ...
ipAllocationPolicy:
  clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.48.0.0/14
  clusterIpv4CidrBlock: 10.48.0.0/14
   servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.0.0.0/20
  servicesIpv4CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/20
   useIpAliases: true
labelFingerprint: a9dc16a7
legacyAbac: {}
location: europe-west1-c
locations:
- europe-west1-c
loggingService: logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes
maintenancePolicy:
  resourceVersion: e3b0c442
masterAuth:
  clusterCaCertificate:
masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig: {}
monitoringService: monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes
name: cluster-prod
network: default
networkConfig:
  network: .../global/networks/default
  subnetwork: .../regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/default
networkPolicy: {}
nodeConfig:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  machineType: g1-small
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
  preemptible: true
  serviceAccount: default
  shieldedInstanceConfig:
    enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
nodePools:
- autoscaling: {}
  config:
    diskSizeGb: 100
    diskType: pd-standard
    imageType: COS
    machineType: g1-small
    metadata:
      disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
    preemptible: true
    serviceAccount: default
    shieldedInstanceConfig:
      enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
  initialNodeCount: 1
  instanceGroupUrls:
  - ...
  locations:
  - europe-west1-c
  management:
    autoRepair: true
    autoUpgrade: true
  maxPodsConstraint:
    maxPodsPerNode: '110'
  name: default-pool
  podIpv4CidrSize: 24
  status: RUNNING
  upgradeSettings:
    maxUnavailable: 1
  version: 1.18.10-gke.2101
notificationConfig:
  pubsub:
    enabled: true
    topic: projects/...
releaseChannel:
  channel: RAPID
servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.0.0.0/20
shieldedNodes:
  enabled: true
status: RUNNING
subnetwork: default
zone: europe-west1-c
```

Comment: Hello. Can you tell more about the setup you're having? The `GKE` version you are using? Any example that could be followed for reproduction?

Comment: Version shouldn't matter as the cluster was upgraded several times. This is a simplest setup you can have, just a manually deployed cluster via GCP Console. I've added some info in the post.

Comment: I used exact same setup as yours (single `g1-small` node with update from `1.18.10-gke.2101` to `1.18.10-gke.2701`) and I couldn't replicate the issue you are describing. Could you tell more about the workload you are scheduling? Could you check the `Deployment` status (describe) and if there any logs that could point why it isn't scheduled? Could you attach the logs from the node (from Stackdriver and `$ kubectl describe node`)  at the time this issue is affecting you?

Comment: Workload does not matter to the cluster setup. The Deployment is not deployed for the reason I mentioned, the preemptible node is recreated by GCP and it is not uncordoned after creation, that's it. When I uncordon it manually, everything works fine.
Something has changed though, for the last couple of days it's fine, so maybe the problem was fixed somewhere behind the scenes. I can see the node that was previously running for 7d was recreated yesterday and properly uncordoned.

Comment: @DawidKruk which tracker is valid to report such bug directly? I see there is no such component in https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: You can report `GKE` issues on Issuetracker.google.com by following this link (it's already in a right component): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=1162666 . Please consider editing your comment as you've included `project-id` which is considered to be PII (personally identifiable information). Also please consider checking this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#what_channel_should_i_use) when choosing a `GKE` release channel.

Comment: Thanks, reported under https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175198977